# ValueError: Field 'song_id' expected a number but got 'Remove from Favourites '

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

ValueError: Field 'song_id' expected a number but got 'Remove from Favourites'. Django Music web App: I have added "Add to Favourite" feature, But Can't add "Remove from Favourite" feature

#models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):
    song_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 2000)
    singer = models.CharField(max_length= 2000)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'docs')
    song = models.FileField(upload_to= 'docs')
    movie = models.CharField(max_length = 150, default = "None")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Favourites(models.Model):
    watch_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video_id = models.CharField(max_length=10000000, default="")
```

Favourite.html [It's right]

```
<form action="/music/favourites" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="video_id" value="{{song.song_id}}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Add to Favourite</button>
</form>
```

#Its wrong

```
<form  method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Remove from Favourites" 
name={{song.id}} >        
</form>
```

#Views.py [ Right ]

```
def favourites(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        video_id = request.POST['video_id']

        fav = Favourites.objects.filter(user=user)
        
        for i in fav:
            if video_id == i.video_id:
                message = "Your Video is Already Added"
                break

        else:
            favourites = Favourites(user=user, video_id=video_id)
            favourites.save()
            message = "Your Video is Succesfully Added"

        song = Song.objects.filter(song_id=video_id).first()
        return render(request, f"music/songpost.html", {'song': song, "message": message})

    wl = Favourites.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    ids = []
    for i in wl:
        ids.append(i.video_id)
    
    preserved = Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(ids)])
    song = Song.objects.filter(song_id__in=ids).order_by(preserved)

    return render(request, "music/favourite.html", {'song': song})
```

This function is not right ,But i can't figuire out

```
def remove_from_favourite(request, song_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        query = Song.objects.filter(id=song_id).first()       
        query.delete()
        messages.success(request, "Removed from favorite!")
        return redirect('favourite', song_id=song_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing the HTML as follows

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="{{song.id}}" 
name={{song.id}} >
```